# Certificate not issued by clusterIssuer EKS

Tags: amazon-eks, cert-manager

I have tried using `jetstack/cert-manager` to secure my application launched on EKS but I still see a **Not Secure** I am not sure what i missed. Here is what i have done

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-production
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: something@gmail.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-production
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
```

My manifest looks as follows

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: wordpress
          image: wordpress:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress
spec:
  selector:
    app: wordpress
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-production
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: wordpress
                port:
                  number: 80
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - mydomain.com
      secretName: letsencrypt-production
```

When i do

```
kubectl describe certificate letsencrypt-production
```

I dont see anything under events like Issued or Requested

```
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2022-12-22T06:04:30Z
    Message:               Certificate is up to date and has not expired
    Observed Generation:   1
    Reason:                Ready
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Ready
  Not After:               2023-03-21T11:04:22Z
  Not Before:              2022-12-21T11:04:23Z
  Renewal Time:            2023-02-19T11:04:22Z
Events:                    <none>
```

When i open my domain i see **NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID**

What did i miss any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I can get it to work by creating a cluster-issuer

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-production
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: <my_email_id>
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-production
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
```

creating an ingress resource as follows.

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-production
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: wordpress
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - mydomain.com
      secretName: letsencrypt-production
```